# Как обрезать блок по высоте?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть что-то вроде такой конструкции:

```css
.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.block>div {
  padding: 5px;
}

.div1 {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="div1">
    Название название название название
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim Ut enim ad mi veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute exercitation ullamco lab exercitation ullamco lab
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

То есть блок фиксированной высоты, в котором блоки.
Как сделать так, чтобы при увеличении высоты первого блока (если вдруг появится еще одна строка) второй блок становился меньше по высоте, никак не затрагивая третий блок?
Пробовал `overflow: hidden`, но решение не надежное (по крайней мере в моем исполнении), потому что может обрезать часть строки.

Comment: Не ясно, что вы называете первым, вторым и третим блоками. Перенесите, пожалуйста, код сюда, дайте блокам `id` и называйте по ним, чтобы все понимали о чём речь.

Comment: А контент второго блока куда девать, если он становится меньше?

Comment: @РашенБеар скрывать

Comment: @riyga скрывать = обрезать, все как вы и хотите. Или вы под «скрывать» что-то другое подразумеваете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое просто решения для таких задач:

```css
.block {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 270px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  line-height: 21px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block>div {
  padding: 5px;
}

.div1 {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.v2 .div3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="div1">
    Название название
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim Ut enim ad mi veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute exercitation ullamco lab exercitation ullamco lab
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block v2">
  <div class="div1">
    Название название название название название название название
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim Ut enim ad mi veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute exercitation ullamco lab exercitation ullamco lab
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если коротко, то добавляем абсолютную позицию для кнопки, а остальное будет обрезаться блоком.